# Как работать с сервисом Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Хочу написать скрипт пагинации таблицы.
Сделал директиву с темплейтом таблицы (куда загружаю данные) и кнопкой вперед.

По моей логике - я вызываю из контроллера метод сервиса, который делает slice полученному массиву данных

```
function getReadyItems(firstitem,lastitem) {
   var last = lastitem;
   var first = firstitem;
   return vm.items.slice(first,last);
}
```

Соответственно, я хочу кнопками менять состояние переменных last и first, которую хочу нажимать в директиве. Для своего понимания хочу сделать пока просто кнопку "вперед" (без всяких проверок на ограничения).

В контроллере директивы делаю функцию

```
vm.nextPage = function() {
    vm.first = vm.first + 5;
    vm.last = vm.last + 5;
    vm.filtereddata = tableService.getReadyItems(vm.first,vm.last);   
};
```

Но повторно массив не обновляется, хотя переменные передаются. В общем, какая логика работы сервиса, чтобы он обновлял данные при передаче в него новых переменных?

Вот [пример моего кода](http://plnkr.co/edit/VKShMjTSsN36s6OUsybv?p=preview)

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пример кода желательно вставлять прямо в вопрос. для исправления вопроса нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: А я как сделал? И примеры кода поставил и ссылку на планкер. Или не так что-то?

Comment: стоило добавить код всей директивы, так как приведенные куски кода - верны

Comment: если весь код, присутствующий по ссылке, приведён в вопросе, то последняя фраза *Вот пример моего кода* (со ссылкой), вероятно, немного вводит в заблуждение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема в этой строке:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ::table.filtereddata">
```

Так как используется one-time binding - после первого получения данных watcher снимается и не реагирует на изменение этой коллекции.

Comment: Да, конечно, спасибо!!!! Увидел, что это экономит ватчеры и поставил где не попадя